# Provide alias for Ruby's built-in keyword

Tags: ruby

For example, I want to make [`Object#rescue`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-rescue) another name so I can use in my code like:

```
def dangerous
  something_dangerous!
dont_worry # instead of rescue here
  false
end
```

I tried

```
class ::Object
  alias :dont_worry :rescue
end
```

But cannot find the `rescue` method on `Object`:

```
`<class:Object>': undefined method `rescue' for class `Object' (NameError)
```

Another example is I would like to have `when` in the language to replace:

```
if cond
  # eval when cond is truthy
end
```

to

```
when cond
  # eval when cond is truthy
end
```

1. Is it possible to give a Ruby keyword alias done in Ruby?
2. Or I need to hack on Ruby [C source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/parse.y)?

Thanks!

Comment: yeah, you can't alias _keywords_. Only methods.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: And global variables.

Comment: There is another option: "3. Make do with Ruby's keywords".

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible without some deep changes to the Ruby language itself. The things you describe are not methods but keywords of the language, i.e. the actual core of what is Ruby. As such, these things are not user-changeable at all.

If you still want to change the names of the keywords, you would at least have to adapt the language parser. If you don't change semantics at all, this might do it as is. But if you want to change what these keywords represent, things get messy really quick.

Also note that Ruby in itself is sometimes quite ambiguous (e.g. with regards to parenthesis, dots, spacing) and goes to great length to resolve this in a mostly consistent way. If you change keywords, you would have to ensure that things won't get any more ambiguous. This could e.g. happen with your change of `if` to `when`. `when` is used as a keywords is `case` statements already and would thus could be a source of ambiguity when used as an `if`.